# Perl Parallel::Forkmanager doesn't allow to collect variable values

Tags: perl, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Maybe because the child processes are not aware of my hash (see the below code), the hash %output is not collecting anything .. is there any other way to collect the value apart from writing a tmp file ?

```
foreach $Item (@AllItems) {
$pid = $pm->start($Item) and next;
$Temp = qx($Item);
$output{$Item}= $Temp; // This doesn't collect anything. :-(
$pm->finish;
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

TIA,
Tim

Comment: You are missing `use strict; use warnings;`, which would give you a lot more insight into why things don't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forked processes have their own copies (well, copies-on-write) of the parent process's memory. Writing to the hash in a child process won't affect the hash in the parent.

To do what you want, you'll need to employ some sort of IPC. See the [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) manpage for a lengthy discussion of the various possibilities.

For something like this, I'd probably use something simple like an on-disk hash. [DB_File](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/DB_File/DB_File.pm) provides a nice tied hash interface. Here's how you might do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DB_File;

tie my %output, "DB_File", "output.dat" ;

foreach my $item( @AllItems) { 
    my $pid = $pm->start and next;
    $output{$item} = qx($item);
    $pm->finish;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each process has its own memory, and data is not shared between processes. But you have several options:

1. Write data from child processes to temp files to be read in parent, as you suggest
2. Use sockets or pipes to accomplish the same thing
3. Use [`threads`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/threads) with [shared variables](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/threads::shared) instead of fork()
4. Use a shared memory facility (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074949/looking-for-a-perl-module-to-store-a-hash-structure-in-shared-ram), for example)
5. Use a lightweight database (SQLLite, maybe `DBD::CSV`). This is a fancy way of using temporary files.

Any more? I don't have any idea how to use the builtin `shmget`/`shmread`/`shmwrite` functions or if they might be helpful here. Other commenters please feel free to edit.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the right modules fro this job ? Tia.

Comment: Named pipes are also a good way to get the data back to the parent.